# ChartIQ addSeries overlay

Tags: charts

Is it possible in ChartIQ to have a series added with `addSeries` to display as an overlay on top of the chart, as is possible with the `addStudy` method (Search for overlay [in here](http://legacydocs.chartiq.com/tutorial-Studies.html))?

I am rendering a histogram with an STX.Renderer.Histogram, and it appears behind the prices mountain chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chartiq/dfy8nszb

It renders the mountain chart and then the histogram over it by setting `overChart: true`

Like so:

```
// create your histogram renderer
var histRenderer = stxx.setSeriesRenderer(new STX.Renderer.Histogram({
  params: {
    type: "histogram",
    subtype: "stacked",
    heightPercentage: .3, // how high to go. 1 = 100%
    opacity: 1, // only needed if supporting IE8, otherwise can use rgba values in histMap instead
    widthFactor: .8, // to control space between bars. 1 = no space in between
    yAxis: axis,    // separate axis
    overChart: true // <<<<<=== if omitted the histogram will be drawn under the main chart.
  },
  callback: histogramLegend
}));
```

Comment: Opacity: 1 was what was needed.

Comment: `opacity: 1` just makes is solid colors, so it may look like it is over the mountain chart ...but really `overChart: true` is what makes it render on top.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out the isComparison flag in params then a series should display as an overlay. If you want the series and the chart to share the same y-axis (the values are in the same range) then set shareYAxis flag to true. That will most approximate using a series as if it were a study.

Comment: I leave the flag out, and it does not appear as an overlay. I only use display and data in addSeries as options.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to call the addSeries()? (You do also need to at least include a color).

Comment: Posted the code here, probably need to use it locally, it doesn't recognize STX.renderer.histogram for some reason http://jsfiddle.net/shabuzdem/3uy5pw46/

Comment: You are missing the "stxLibrary.js" include where that constructor is defined. Your first argument to stxx.newChart (`ticker`) also seems to be undefined.

Comment: Hi the main issue is that your array of data is in reverse order. studyData.reverse() should fix the issue.